# sass npm delete prefix

Tags: npm, sass, vendor-prefix

When I put this in my .scss file :

```
webkit-animation-play-state: running;
-moz-animation-play-state: running;
-ms-animation-play-state: running;
-o-animation-play-state: running;
animation-play-state: running;
```

After compiling ("npm start") I only get this :

```
animation-play-state: running;
```

Why ? And how can I fix this ?
Thank you in advance

(the same thing appends with translate, keyframe…)

*npm version : 2.15.8
node version : v4.4.7*

Comment: What packages are being used? And what are you running your build with? Grunt, Gulp? If I could make a suggestion, I'd say use the autoprefixer package that way you can have animation-play-state and the autoprefixer package will apply the correct browser-prefixes

Comment: I used Gulp, where autoprefix was installed so I just had to change his config : "browsers: ['last 5 versions']"